# Return in the middle of a loop

Tags: java, return

I have to write a function to remove a element from a linkedlist (mine, not that of Collections framework), so here is my first attempt :

```
public void remove(E element) {
    Cell<E> cell = sentinel;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
        if (cell.getElement().equals(element)) {
            cell.getPrevious().setNext(cell.getNext());
            --count;
            return;
        }
        ++i;
        cell = cell.getNext();
    }
}
```

My question is : is using `return` like this is good ?
More generally, when the condition is checked and there is no point running the following instructions, then it made sense to me to use `return` :

```
void func() {
    while (condition) {
        if (something) {
            instructions;
            return;
        }
        more instructions;
    }
}
```

But since it was not very readable and everybody says that readability is the priority in java, I had to think of another approach. So I changed the condition and used a additional boolean.

```
public void remove(E element) {
    boolean found = false;
    Cell<E> cell = sentinel;
    int i = 0;
    while (!found && i < count) {
        if (cell.getElement().equals(element))
            found = true;
        else {
            ++i;
            cell = cell.getNext();
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        cell.getPrevious().setNext(cell.getNext());
        --count;
    }
}
```

In that way, there is no weird `return` and instructions are executed only when they have to be. If I am confronted to this again, I think I will have to re-write the loop like this. 
Maybe I am totally wrong and the first approach is better. What do you think of it ?

Comment: `return` is perfect in your first method

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. I prefer to return in the middle of the loop, since I think that the extra variables (i.e. the boolean `found`) detract from readability. Also, note your second approach isn't the same as your first boolean you call `cell=cell.next()` one extra time.

Comment: _But since it was not very readable.._ Well, who said that's not readable? I guess it's more readable than the second one.

Comment: Well, to me it was not

Comment: Would you still think the first style is less readable if you used `break` instead of `return`? It'd be functionally the same, and avoids extra variables, but only has a single return point.

Comment: Readability is a fairly subjective area overall but there are a few proxies you can use: fewer variables, fewer statements/expressions, simpler conditionals, fewer branches and fewer nested blocks generally result in better readability. All that seems to indicate that your first solution is probably more readable for most people, despite the fact that a `return` from a loop muddles up the control flow somewhat. But if you have multiple `return` statements in various places, the situation may reverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion returning early is perfectly fine, if it's not too complex. Similar to using a break statement to break out of the loop early.

You can look at this Question on Programmers, they each raise valid points.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Answer (score 1):

Separate logic in functions that some only read and some only change state. If you will have a find-something function it will be clear to make return in the middle of search process

For example

```
public void remove(E element) {
    Cell<E> cell = FindCell(element);
    if (cell != null)
        RemoveCell(cell);
}

private <E> FindCell(E element) {
    <E> cell = sentinel;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
        if (cell.getElement().equals(element)) {
            return cell;
        }
        ++i;
        cell = cell.getNext();
    }

    return null;
}

private void RemoveCell(<E> cell) {
    cell.getPrevious().setNext(cell.getNext());
    --count;
}
```

This separation give you some advantages. You can call read-only functions as many times as you want (may be in parallel threads) and you definitely know that nothing happens. C++, for example, has const-functions

And return is very convinient when you need to break two or more nested cycles

Answer (score 0):

It is completely a matter of choice and their's nothing wrong with any of the mentioned way to come out of the loop, just two things to keep in mind..

> Return can be used when you do not want to execute rest of the code outside loop on that particular method and go back to the caller.
>
> boolean `true or false` can be used when you do not want to execute the
>   loop anymore but you still want to continue with rest of the code in
>   that method.